# Moving from bracket notation to dot notation for accessing forms?

Tags: javascript

jshint gives the error:

```
Line 362: document.forms['upload_form'].submit();
['upload_form'] is better written in dot notation.
```

for this line

```
document.forms['upload_form'].submit();
```

What dot notation...are they talking about accessing the object memmber via the '.' operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; what other dot notation is there?

As you continue to ask jshint-related questions, bear in mind that some of the checks it performs are preferential: it's more important to remain consistent, and you can configure it to better-conform to your own particular style.

Also, bear in mind that for forms with array-notation names (`tag[]` or whatever), you'd need to use array notation anyway--I'd rather see the use of a single means of accessing form properties.

Comment: Can I use the dot notation when the form name is contained in a variable?

Comment: @stack.user.1 I'm not sure what you mean, but if you mean `var s = 'upload_form'` and want to use `document.forms.s`, then no; that would be equivalent to `document.forms['s']`. But `document.forms[s]` would get the `upload_form` in that case.

Comment: in short...no dot notation with variables

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of dot notation

```
document.upload_form.submit()
```

Here is some reference.
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html

In addition I guess its best explained that all everything in JavaScript is Object Based.

Consider the following

```
var myobject = {value1 : 1, value2: 2};
```

I can access value1 and value2 like this

```
myobject.value1;
myobject["value1"];
```

Comment: even though upload_form is just the name attribute in my html for my form..this will work?

Comment: Becasue it is a string..I would have expected quotes some where?

Comment: It works.  This is part of how the DOM responds to form names.   Form elements can also be accessed in a similar fashion.

Comment: Not just DOM, folks. http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html this is JavaScript.